# How to paginate fetched data from API in React Native

Tags: pagination, react-native

I am trying to paginate the records that are fetched using API. I have no idea how to add pagination.  my code is :

```
handlePressProduct(id) {
    var url='http://www.example.com/menu_category_listing.php?cat_id='; 
    fetch(url+id, {
    method: 'GET'
    }).then((response) => { return response.json() } )
    .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);          Actions.category({dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),data:responseJson,})     
    })

      }
```

its posting data properly to Actions.category(). data is too large so its take time to load. so i need to add pagination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pagination in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49452707/pagination-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

i think it'll be better if you made the pagination on the server.